# using ajax in react component render

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a list of contents link, when user clicks item, an ajax request is sent to server and received data should be shown in a react component. I used `componentWillReceiveProps` to send my requests, but refresh the url doesn't work (Router doesn't call component).

it's index.js file:

```
 render((
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
                <Route path="/content/:id" component={UmContent} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

it's App.js file's "render" function:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>App</h1>
            <ul>{this.renderItems()}</ul>
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    );
}
```

and it's UmContent.js file:

```
 export default class UmContent extends Component {
    state = {
        data: ''
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(props) {

        if (!props || !props.params || !props.params.id) {
            return;
        }
        console.log(props.params.id);
        let itemId = props.params.id;
        let that = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://192.168.78.2:8585/Default/mygetcontenttoactionresult/" + itemId,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'
        }).done((data)=> {
            that.setState({data: data});
        }).fail(()=> {
            that.setState({data: <div> Something is wrong</div>});
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div ref="aaa">
                <UmC content={this.state.data}/>
            </div>);
    }
}
```

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` only fires when your component actually gets new props.  Where is this happening?

Comment: @MichaelParker actually my component should use url parameters to update itself, so I think just props.params is changed.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm trying to say.  `componentWillReceiveProps` is part of the [React lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops), and it doesn't fire when the component is mounted, only *after* it is mounted and the component gets new props.  Is your ajax request actually firing?  If so, what props is your component receiving in order for it to do so?

Comment: @MichaelParker : I understood :) and answer . when url is changed , componentWillReceiveProps will be fired .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you did something wrong. I rewrite your code for myself.

`ContentWrapper` to wrap `Content` component:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import Content from './content';

class ContentWrapper extends Component {
  state = {
    params: '/something',
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    // Simulate react-router property changing
    setTimeout(() => {this.setState({params: '/something-else'})})
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Content params={this.state.params} />
    )
  }
}

module.exports = ContentWrapper;
```

`Content` component:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
var $ = require("jquery");

class Content extends Component {
  state = {
    text: 'Pending...'
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://192.168.78.2:8585/Default/mygetcontenttoactionresult/item",
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json'
    }).done((data)=> {
      this.setState({text: 'Success'});
    }).fail(()=> {
      this.setState({text: 'Fail'});
    });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <span>
        {this.state.text}
      </span>
    )
  }
}

module.exports = Content;
```

This works for me.
Are you sure `componentWillReceiveProps` is called when route is changed?

Comment: I find some typo and fixed them .yes it is called. when I click browser backward or forward button it's called too . but now doesn't work just in refresh page.isn't called just for refresh.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for comments and answer. right component:

```
export default class UmContent extends Component {
state = {
    data: ''
}

firstInitial = true;

componentDidMount() {
    if (this.firstInitial) {
        let props = this.props;
        this.sendRequestToServer(props);
        this.firstInitial = false;
    }
}

sendRequestToServer = (props)=> {
    if (!props || !props.params || !props.params.id) {
        return;
    }
    console.log(props.params.id);
    let itemId = props.params.id;
    let that = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://192.168.78.2/mygetcontenttoactionresult/" + itemId,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html'
    }).done((data)=> {
        that.setState({data: data});
    }).fail(()=> {
        that.setState({data: <div> Something is wrong</div>});
    });
}

componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    this.sendRequestToServer(props);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div ref="aaa">
            <UmC content={this.state.data}/>
        </div>);
}
}
```

now, I just want to know:why every request is sent twice?