# ReactJS - AJAX call in componentWillMount

Tags: ajax, reactjs

[React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html) suggest to fetch initial data in `componentDidMount` function. For my it is not intuitive because we could do it sooner in `componentWillMount` (first function from [React component life cycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html)). In general I think we should start AJAX calls us soon us possible so user doesn't have to wait for them. So why do we have to wait until component is rendered?

My questions are:

- Are there any problems with using AJAX in `componentWillMount`?
- Are there any benefits of using AJAX in `componentDidMount`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

say you do AJAX on `componentWillMount`

```
componentWillMount(){
   this.serverRequest = $.get(...);
}
```

Now you have a pending AJAX request. Its a good practice to cancel this request when the component is unmounted

```
componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
}
```

but lets say for whatever reason the component did not mount. you still have your pending ajax request which can not be cancelled anywhere (since component is not mounted, `componentWillUnmount` won't be reached) thus creating a memory leak.

If you had put the ajax request on `componentDidMount` you had a guarantee that the `componentWillUnmount` will fire since component is mounted allowing you to cleanup your request safely

Answer (score 1):

Simply create the component when you have the data and pass it through props. Have the parent component (if you have one) to do the request.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your task. for example I have used an ajax request in componentWillReceiveProps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39350121/using-ajax-in-react-component-render/39356326#39356326). what is your concern exactly? what does your ajax?